# vhost setup for multiple SVN repositories on same server

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, virtualhost, webdav

I have 2 svn repos on my EC2 instance.
They are located in `/ebs/svn/repo1` & `/ebs/svn/repo2`.

I have created a domain alias `svn.mydomain.com`, to point to the parent directory of above (`/ebs/svn`).

I woud like to access each of the above repo's using the following URL format:
`svn.mydomain.com/repo1`
`svn.mydomain.com/repo2`

Currenly I have the repo1 working with the following vhosts config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName svn.mydomain.com
        ServerAlias svn.mydomain.com
        ErrorLog /var/www/html/log/svn.mydomain.com-log
        <Location "/" >
            DAV svn
            SVNPath /ebs/svn/repo1
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "SVN - Private - Repos"
            AuthUserFile /ebs/svn/login/svn-auth-conf
            Require valid-user
       </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is, I can only get access to `repo1` through the above vhosts config.

I would like to access both repo's in the following format:
`svn.mydomain.com/repo1`
`svn.mydomain.com/repo2`

What do I need to change to access my svn repo's by their directories?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have set the `SVNPath` directive, you have "hard coded" the path:

```
SVNPath /ebs/svn/repo1
```

Try using the `SVNParentPath` directive instead, to configure the "top" directory that will hold all your repositories. Replace the above line with this:

```
SVNParentPath /ebs/svn/
```

If you want to allow users to view a list of all the available repositories if they just go to `svn.mydomain.com`, you should also add this line:

```
SVNListParentPath on
```

That will allow the listing of all your repositories. Otherwise, a "Forbidden" page will be shown on `svn.mydomain.com` rather than a list of repositories.

To sum up, here's a complete location block example :

```
    ‹Location "/"›
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /ebs/svn/
        SVNListParentPath On
        SSLRequireSSL
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "svn ebs"
        AuthUserFile conf/svnpasswd 
        Require valid-user
    ‹/Location›
```

Comment: Was getting double teamed by "forbidden" and "Could not open the requested SVN filesystem" errors all morning. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

**What I did:** (As answered by @Oldskool)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName svn.mydomain.com
        ServerAlias svn.mydomain.com
        ErrorLog /var/www/html/log/svn.mydomain.com-log
        <Location "/" >
            DAV svn
            # Delete SVNPath!
            SVNParentPath /ebs/svn/ # add this!
            SVNListParentPath on #Lists all the repos!! coool stuff! :D
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Private - Repos"
            AuthUserFile /ebs/svn/login/svn-auth-conf
            Require valid-user
       </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

***Thanks @Oldskool!***

---

**Old Way**
This is an older way I found, but for multiple repositries, you will have to add multiple  tags. **(Use @oldSkool's answer above, works much better!)**
(Noticed the `<Location "/repo1">`, So basically, add a new location for each repo.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName svn.mydomain.com
        ServerAlias svn.mydomain.com
        ErrorLog /var/www/html/log/svn.mydomain.com-log
        <Location "/repo1" >
            DAV svn
            SVNPath /ebs/svn/repo1
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Private - Repo1"
            AuthUserFile /ebs/svn/login/svn-auth-conf
            Require valid-user
        </Location>
        <Location "/repo2" >
            DAV svn
            SVNPath /ebs/svn/repo2
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Private - Repo2"
            AuthUserFile /ebs/svn/login/svn-auth-conf
            Require valid-user
       </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You can do that, but it requires you to add every new repo seperately. Also check out my answer for a more generic approach.