# After svn switch - (405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED) or (500 Internal Server Error), why?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, webdav, svn

I have recently (today!), moved my SVN repository to my own server.

I am having trouble checking out from my new repo and also updating my current working copy to use my new repo (which is a `svnsync` copy from my old repo), I did this by using:

`svn switch --relocate /old/repo/path /new/repo/path`

This worked as expected and threw a common uuid error.
I first got an error `svn uuid's dont match`, so I updated the `uuid` file in the svn repo config `(repo/db/uuid)` to reflect the old `uuid`. This got rid of that error.

Everything below are my issues, I can't do anything with my new repo (I want to change my old working copy to use my new repo (which I created then svn synced from my old repo to new). So the only difference is the uuid (which I manually changed), the revision's are exactly the same (nothing added or removed).

Next, I tried to checkout a new Working copy of my repo:
(First make new dir, and try to checkout new repo):

**SVN checkout Error:**

```
# Error after trying to checkout new working copy
# 'svn co http://svn.mydomain.com/repo1 .'
svn: E175002: Server sent unexpected return value (405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED) in response to REPORT request for '/newtbg/!svn/me'
```

**SVN up Error:** (same error as above)

```
# Error after 'svn up'
svn: E175002: Server sent unexpected return value (405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED) in response to REPORT request for '/newtbg/!svn/me'
```

**SVN commit -m "commit test"**

```
# Error after ' svn commit -m "test" '
svn: E175002: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to POST request for '/newtbg/!svn/me'
```

It seems that I may have set something up wrong?.

You can view my vhosts config setup here: [vhost setup for multiple SVN repositories on same server](https://serverfault.com/questions/461144/vhost-setup-for-multiple-svn-repositories-on-same-server)

***To Summarize...!***
I have a new repo `svn sync'd` from my old repo. I relocated the working copy URL to my new svn repo url (`svn sw oldUrl newUrl`), then I updated the UUID to match the old repo to get rid off the `UUID's don't match` error.

*Update: Forgot to mention, I can access my repo through the browser using the repo URL, I am displayed with the revision number & repo files, so it does work!! (i think! :S)*

**added my vhosts.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName svn.mydomain.com
        ServerAlias svn.mydomain.com
        ErrorLog /var/www/html/log/svn.mydomain.com-log
        <Location "/" >
            DAV svn
            SVNParentPath /ebs/svn/
            SVNListParentPath on
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Private - Repositries"
            AuthUserFile /ebs/svn/login/svn-auth-conf
            Require valid-user
       </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: have you granted the good rights for svn user in your server?

Comment: currently, everything is owned by ec2-user (all svn repos), I changed this to apache:apache and it didn't make any difference, I am using  Amazon EC2 linux AMI. Not sure if this is right?

Comment: 1/ You must to read Apache error-log for real error detection (and maybe show errors here) 2/ You fix UUID in the wrong style, correct way is `svnadmin setuuid` command (JFYI, unrelated to mentioned errors) 3/ 405 error *may means* access-rights problem of your authenticated svn-user for reading repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK!
Figured it out!.. The issue was that I was behind a load balancer (which I was planning to get rid of anyway). So I removed my EC2 instance from the load balancer, and everything started to work again!..

So if you having these issues, make sure your not behind a Amazon load balancer (or find a workaround).

All this time, I thought this was a SVN issue, it turned out to be something to do with the server. My SVN setup was fine!.

After I fixed this issue, I accidentally committed to my old repository!, Then when I tried to commit to my new repositry, It was out of sync. So I had to `svnsync sync file:///path/to/repo` to get it all in sync again!.

All in all, great learning curve with SVN (new repo, syncing, errors & finally success!!), and hope this saves someone abit of time!!

Everything works great now! **:D**